# SSH -X Launch only the start menu

Tags: ssh, kubuntu, 20.04, kde

I'm currently working a lot from a windows laptop accessing through SSH -X to my Kubuntu powerfull desktop.

I launch my applications easily and it is way more convinient than a RDP in my honest opinion.

The only problem remaining, is when I have to launch a program that I don't know the name. Last time is was a PDF viewer... Was it Okular ? Evince ? Something else with the command name really different than the name displayed in the window?

I would like to open through ssh X my start menu in which I could search for applications, setting or file graphically. Ideally only the button.

If it is possible, What is the name of the command to launch that ?
If not, is there another way to do it ? Or a tool that would do that (optionnaly another desktop environnement)?
I cannot think I'm the first to have the idea to do that, but I fail in finding some clues on the internet.

Any help appreciated =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get and use Kubuntu's start menu this way:

1. Start a terminal window and run

   ```
   ssh -X <user@IP-adress-of-your-Kubuntu>
   ```
2. and (in the ssh session) run

   ```
   plasmawindowed org.kde.plasma.kicker
   ```

   and select your application with the GUI name (instead of guessing the command line name).

- You can make an alias for the long command line to make things more convenient.
- When I tested it, I found that the menu was dead after starting a program, so you must exit and re-start the menu, when you need it again.

I found this method at the following link,

- [Run KDE applet from command line (within i3wm)](https://superuser.com/questions/1012790/run-kde-applet-from-command-line-within-i3wm)

---

**Edit**:

- In the Ubuntu family flavours and many other Linux distros, the desktop files to start application programs are stored in the directory `/usr/share/applications`. If you open your file browser there, you can start your programs by clicking the icons of the desktop files, in Kubuntu via

  ```
  dolphin /usr/share/applications
  ```

Comment: thanks for the answer. On my work computer wiht KDE on CentOS, the command is not `plasmawindowed` but `plasma-windowed`, and the appet `plasmawindowed`  does not seems to do something. I will try tonight at home. Do you know how to get the list of applet installed to see if it has another name on my configuration ?

Comment: My experience is limited to Ubuntu, the Ubuntu family flavours (for example Kubuntu) and to some extent Debian. I tested the command with Kubuntu 20.04 LTS and it worked for me. You might have better luck if you search at Red Hat forums for help with the corresponding tools in Red Hat and related distros.

Comment: In the Ubuntu family flavours and many other Linux distros, the desktop files to start application programs are stored in the directory `/usr/share/applications`. So if you open your file browser there, you can start your programs by clicking the icons of the desktop files, in Kubuntu via `dolphin /usr/share/applications`

Comment: Thank you for all your inputs. I found some time this weekend to test on kubuntu, and it works :-). Therefore, I accepted your answer. Have a nice day